# How to fill a jQuery DataTable with AJAX-requested JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

Im trying to use jQuery Datatables filled by a AJAX-requested `json.txt` but for some reason my file does not load into my datatable.

Why is my datatable not filling correctly? Do I have some syntax error?

This is my datatable syntax:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#pftable_hdr').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/path.txt",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Fecha" },
            { "data": "Rid" },
            { "data": "Pdv" },
            { "data": "Pla" },
            { "data": "Descripcion" },
            { "data": "Total" },
            { "data": "Cantidad" }
        ],
        scrollY: "500px",
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        fixedColumns: {
            leftColumns: 3
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the HTML for my table:

```html
<table class="table table-hover no-more-tables table-iconmebanquet-detail" id="pftable_hdr">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="">Fecha</th>
            <th style="">Rid</th>
            <th style="">Pdv</th>
            <th style="">Pla</th>
            <th style="">Descripcion</th>
            <th style="">Total</th>
            <th style="">Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th style="">Fecha</th>
            <th style="">Rid</th>
            <th style="">Pdv</th>
            <th style="">Pla</th>
            <th style="">Descripcion</th>
            <th style="">Total</th>
            <th style="">Cantidad</th>
       </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

And this is my JSON file at the correct route:

```js
[
  {
    "Fecha": "/Date(1451631600000)/",
    "Rid": "CENAS",
    "Pdv": "REST",
    "Pla": "81",
    "Descripcion": "ENS FRUTAS",
    "Total": 53.0000,
    "Cantidad": 1
  },
  {
    "Fecha": "/Date(1451631600000)/",
    "Rid": "CENAS",
    "Pdv": "REST",
    "Pla": "87",
    "Descripcion": "CAFE AMER ILIMIT",
    "Total": 23.0000,
    "Cantidad": 1
  },
  {
    "Fecha": "/Date(1451631600000)/",
    "Rid": "CENAS",
    "Pdv": "REST",
    "Pla": "97",
    "Descripcion": "QUESADILLAS TRAD (2)",
    "Total": 51.0000,
    "Cantidad": 1
  },
  {
    "Fecha": "/Date(1451631600000)/",
    "Rid": "CENAS",
    "Pdv": "VTSI",
    "Pla": "114",
    "Descripcion": "ENS CHIAPANECA",
    "Total": 65.0000,
    "Cantidad": 1
  },
  {
    "Fecha": "/Date(1451631600000)/",
    "Rid": "COMIDAS",
    "Pdv": "VTMO",
    "Pla": "196",
    "Descripcion": "POZ ROJO SUP MAC",
    "Total": 91.0000,
    "Cantidad": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: As a sidenote - do you know that the `url` you have in your code (wrongly) points to your harddrive? You should maybe serve your files with a local server like [hs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or use a `file://` link (with forward slashes instead of backslashes). Backslashes in JavaScript are used to escape data: `"Line 1\nLine 2"`

Comment: i based my ajax syntax in a ejample of the Datatable main page, i have my  txt file in the inetpub site directory of my server so whta would the correct syntax be? because my datatable is always stuck at Loading...

Comment: If the page you're serving is called table.html and is in the `potzolcalli.brain.arpon.com` site then the `url` should just be `./path.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The url to your textfile in your source code is wrong:

```
"url": "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\potzolcalli.brain.arpon.com\path.txt",
```

In JavaScript, a backslash `\` is an escape character for strings, such as a newline character: `"\n"`.

---

You should either use a file:// url:

```
"url": "file://C:/inetpub/wwwroot/potzolcalli.brain.arpon.com/path.txt",
```

or use a local http server to serve your files, e.g. [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), assuming you have [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed:

```
npm install -g http-server
cd <root directory of your files, e.g. your index.html>
http-server
```

You can then open your browser at http://localhost:8080 to consume your site similar to the way they will get served by an http server in production later.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:
i solved the proble changing my Ip by the suggestion of @Leon Adles
so i made the next correction and it dysplayed perfectly now

"url": "/path.txt",

Comment: Please update your question with the "edit" button instead of writing an answer (this is not an answer). If your question is solved by my answer, please mark it as accepted (tickbox under the up/down arrows) so your question does not show up in the "unanswered questions" lists.